# SwiftUI - Set a UIImage based on Binary Data

Tags: swift, swiftui, nestjs

I am attempting to display an image in my SwiftUI app.

I am sending an HTTP request to my nestJS API to retrieve the image. The API returns the image encoded as a Buffer (binary data). Here is what I receive in Swift:

```
"name": "this_test"
"image": {
   "type": "Buffer",
   "data": [
     255,
     216,
     255,
     224,
     ...
   ]
}
```

How can I decode this image and display it ?

Here's my class :

```
import Foundation

struct Buffer: Codable {
    var type: String
    var data: [UInt8]
}

class Tester: Codable {
    public var name: String
    public var image: Buffer
}
```

And what I tried :

```
do {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  let decodedResponse = try decoder.decode(Tester.self, from: data)
  self.image = UIImage(data: decodedResponse.image.data)

} catch {
  print("Can't parse JSON..")
  return
}
```

Comment: "encoded as a Buffer" What exactly is the format? PNG? JPG? Color of each pixel?

Comment: It's a JPG saved in the API that I read using the `fsPromises.readFile(path);` function in JS

Comment: Your attempt is quite close. Does `UIImage(data: Data(decodedResponse.image.data))` work?

Comment: @Sweeper It gaves me the error `No exact matches in call to initializer `. Maybe it's the types I declared in the class

Comment: You declared another type called `Data`? Better rename that, or use `Swift.Data(decodedResponse.image.data)`.

Comment: Nope I used the native Data() function.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://swiftfiddle.com/r3sdjhec5naz7i6bgbhca4h26u).

Comment: @Sweeper OK I tried with `[UInt8]` but with a different Data() constructor. Now with your example it is working thank you

Comment: ```let imageData: Data```
```imageData = Data(base64Encoded: base64Data)```

just do this and then

```if let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {```